# How to align child element of parent div?

Tags: html, css

My code seems like this right now, I mainly use flexbox but I couldn't manage to vertically align "Sign up" button.

```css
.fourth-section{
display: flex;
margin-top: 70px;
justify-content: center;
}

.cta-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 760px;
    background-color: #3882F6;
    padding: 30px;
}

.cta-texts{
    width: 450px;
}

#signup{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    outline:2px;
    outline-style:solid;
    outline-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #3882F6;
    padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
    width: 150px;
    align-self:flex-end;   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Landing Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       
            <div class="fourth-section">
                <div class="cta-container">
                    <div class="cta-texts">
                    <header id="cta-header">Call to action! It's time!</header>
                    <p>Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!</p> 
                    </div>
                    <button id="signup">Sign up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I've been trying to align this for a while now. Sign up button should be like in the second image.

[This is mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYqcn.png)

[This is how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QElaq.png)

P.S I'm so beginner to stackoverflow as well as web development, sorry about little information I provide earlier.

Comment: Cool. So what have you tried so far? And what is your code?

Comment: https://codepen.io/akinpinkman/pen/qBoVwgY Here is my code, sorry about that I forgot to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the flex-box properties [read here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp), so you can separate the containers you have into columns and rows. Here is an example

```html
<style>
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color:#3b82f6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
}
.col-1{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}
.col-2{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.signup-button{
    background-color:#3b82f6;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
}

</style>

<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='col-1'>
        <b>Call to action! it's time!</b>
        <span>Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!</span>
    </div>
    <div class='col-2'>
        <button class='signup-button'>Sign up</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Next time, as a minimum requirement to ask a question, you must show what you have tried to do on your side.